# Test IF in Subscribe using Karma and Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, jasmine, angular6

I'm doing unit testing in Angular 6, but I'm having trouble testing this `IF` branch. I use it to observe how big the screen is, and so to decide how many columns I'll display. I'm struggling with how to test inside the subscribe that is in `ngOnInit()`.

This

```
 this.watcher = this.media.subscribe((change: MediaChange) =>....
```

code coverage show that it does not go into the `if` and `else` of these services. This was the best I could do. The Media Change service keeps looking at which screen size, to decide how many columns it would display in the table

```js
  ngOnInit() {
        this.watcher = this.media.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
          this.activeMediaQuery = change ? `'${change.mqAlias}' = (${change.mediaQuery})` : '';
          this.changeMqAlias = change.mqAlias;

          if (this.changeMqAlias == this.changeSize.XS) {

            this.displayedColumns = ['job', 'name', 'totalValue'];
          } else {
            this.displayedColumns = ['internalId', 'DateOfPublication', 'alias', 'job', 'name', 'totalValue'];
          }
          return change.mqAlias;
        });
      }
```

The File Test

```js
it('should create', () => {
                fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                  
                  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
                });
              });

              it('should create which 3 columns in mat table', () => {
                fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                  component.changeMqAlias = 'xs';
                  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
                });
              });
             
            });
```

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking.  If you have written a spec then please post the code you have attempted yourself.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I hope I have clarified, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways you could approach this.  The key to testing inside the subscribe is that you must mock the `ObservableMedia` service such that it returns an observable.  Then you can change the values of `component.changeMqAlias` to different values and see that your 'if' resolves properly both ways.

I have set up a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53934411?file=app%2Fmy.component.spec.ts) to show you one approach to testing the function as given.  Here is the `describe` from that Stackblitz:

```
describe('app testing', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
    const mockFlex = of({ // create an Observable that returns a desired result
        mqAlias: 'xs',
        mediaQuery: 'test mQ'
    });

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ MatTableModule /* Other imports needed */ ],
            declarations: [ MyComponent ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ObservableMedia, useValue: mockFlex }
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    }));

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
    it('should have 3 columns in mat table when changeMqAlias === "xs"', () => {
        component.changeMqAlias = 'xs';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.displayedColumns).toEqual(['job', 'name', 'totalValue']);
    });
        it('should have 6 columns in mat table when changeMqAlias !== "xs"', () => {
        component.changeMqAlias = 'xl';
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.displayedColumns.length).toEqual(6);
    });

});
```

Some notes about this:

- You never specified the name of your component, so I just called it `MyComponent`.
- A key to making this work is mocking the ObservableMedia dependency injected in the constructor of your component.  Note the `mockFlex` setup and also that it is substituted in the providers array to the TestBed for `ObservableMedia`.
- Also note that `fixture.detectChanges()` is not called until AFTER `changeMqAlias` has been set.  The reason for this is because `fixture.detectChanges()` will call `ngOnInit()` and you need to have this variable set ahead of time to control the path through your `IF` statement.  Details in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#detectchanges).
- Feel free to Fork this Stackblitz to your own account and play around with it.  If you have further questions in the future, then making a Stackblitz showing the actual issue helps others tremendously to quickly analyze your issue and provide solutions.